# store offline html form data in a csv file

Tags: php, html, forms, csv, fputcsv

I'm looking for a simple solution to what is hopefully a simple problem.  I want to have a laptop set up with an offline html file with a very short form that feeds a csv file.  I've been eyeing the `fputcsv()` function to do this, but I'm not the most talented programmer.  If I have a simple form that looks like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $myfile = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
        fputcsv($myfile,
            array($_POST['first-name'], $_POST['last-name'], $_POST['email']));
        fclose($myfile);
    }
?>

<article role="main">

    <header role="banner">

        <h1>Email Updates</h1> 

    </header> 

    <section>

    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

        <input type="text" id="first-name" maxlength="100" autocorrect placeholder="First name" />
        <input type="text" id="last-name" maxlength="100" autocorrect placeholder="Last name" />
        <input type="text" id="email" maxlength="100" autocorrect placeholder="Email address" />

        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="oneup">Submit</button>

    </form>

    </section> 

</article>
```

what kind of code do I need to have it feed a simple csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this form is submitted, it will populate the $_POST array.

So, you should add some PHP code that handles the submitted values.

For example:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $myfile = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
        fputcsv($myfile,
            array($_POST['first-name'], $_POST['last-name'], $_POST['email']));
        fclose($myfile);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I've added this bit of PHP to my html, but I'm still not seeing any data getting fed to file.csv.  Is it dependent on where I put it?

Comment: Typically this would precede the HTML form code. Make sure your file is being handled by the server as php; i.e. it has a .php extension and the server is correctly recognizing it.

Comment: yep, all of those conditions are met.  Still no results.  Keep in mind that I'm storing the php file offline, so it shouldn't have to connect to any server...

Comment: By server I mean whatever is handling the parsing of the PHP file. I assumed you're running something on your localhost. The browser by itself won't do anything with PHP.

Comment: when I put the form online, I also see nothing populating the csv file...I've editted my original question to include that entire content between my body tags...

Comment: Ok, make a file `test.php` with the following content: `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` and see if that gives any results. If not, you have an entirely different problem than trying to get csv output.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7705/discussion-between-blackessej-and-jyelton)

Answer (score 1):

When (if) the form is submitted (correctly), do this:

```
if( $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w') )
{
  fputcsv($fp, $_POST);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to djot's answer, I'd use this:

```
if( $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w') ){
    fputcsv($fp, print_r($_POST, true));
}
fclose($fp);
```

Note the print_r with the true flag, as this makes it more human readable.

If you actually wanted to write it as a CSV, just use:

```
$data = implode(',' $_POST);
if( $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w') ){
    fputcsv($fp, $data);
}
fclose($fp);
```